# Oracle Mutating table - trigger error

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I get these error when updating  a table

```
ORA-04091: table HAMZA.EXPEDITION is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "HAMZA.LIVRAISONFINIE", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HAMZA.LIVRAISONFINIE'
```

Here are tables used

Expedition(Id_Expedition , Date_Livraison);

Commande(Numero_Commande,..);

cmdalivrer (id_cmd,id_etape);

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER livraisonfinie

AFTER  UPDATE  ON Expedition
FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE
    date_liv Expedition.date_livraison%type;

BEGIN

    SELECT :NEW.date_livraison INTO date_liv from Expedition;

    IF date_liv <> TO_DATE('00/00/00 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
    THEN
        INSERT INTO Commande (etat) VALUES ('livree');

        DELETE FROM cmdalivrer CMD  WHERE :NEW.numero_commande=CMD.id_cmd;
        DELETE FROM Expedition E WHERE E.date_livraison = date_liv;
    END IF ;
END;
/
```

Thanks for helping .

Comment: What is the logic that you are trying to implement?  Why are you selecting from `expedition` in the first place rather than just assigning `:new.date_livraison` to `date_liv` if there is a reason to have the local variable at all?  What is the `delete` from `expedition` trying to do?  A trigger can't delete the row that is in the process of being inserted.  And the comparison against a year of 0 date seems unlikely to be right.  It doesn't look like whatever you want to accomplish should be done through a trigger like this.

Comment: Its like a delivry database. When user update date_livraison attribute that's mean he get delivred so I want to delete the rows in cmdalivrer where numero_livraison of the row get updated = cmdalivrer.id_cmd . then delete the row that just get insered in Expedition ( that's why I used an AFTER trigger. Finally the if check if date_livraison attribute contain 00-00-00 00:00:00 ( which means that the command does not get delivred yet ). ( thanks and sorry for my bad english )

Comment: A trigger on a table isn't going to be able to delete the row that is in the process of being inserted (which is still true whether it's a before or after row trigger).  Rather than having the user insert a row into a table that immediately gets removed, wouldn't it make far more sense for the user to call a procedure that just deletes from the `cmdaliverer` table?

Comment: Because I need to do it with trigger. So if I don't delete the row that trigger and just delete cmdalivrer row , will I have the mutating table problem?

Comment: If you remove the `delete from expedition`, you'd either get a mutating table error or a `too_many_rows` exception from the initial `select` against `expedition`.  If you remove that, the mutating table exception would go away.  It doesn't seem like a sensible approach but you certainly could do it.  My guess is that you'd need the `IF` statement to be `IF :new.date_livraison IS NOT NULL` because I would guess that your `to_date` call would attempt to produce an invalid date assuming you fixed the string to match the format mask.

Comment: The field date_livraison defined already Not null . that's what I have to put a value. So if you could purpose me a rectification that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're trying to do using a compound trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER livraisonfinie_compound
  AFTER  UPDATE ON Expedition
  COMPOUND TRIGGER

  TYPE DATE_TABLE IS TABLE OF EXPEDITION.DATE_LIVRAISON%TYPE;
  tblDates  DATE_TABLE;

  BEFORE STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    tblDates := DATE_TABLE();
  END BEFORE STATEMENT;

  AFTER EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    IF :NEW.date_livraison <> TO_DATE('00/00/00 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
    THEN
        INSERT INTO Commande (etat) VALUES ('livree');

        DELETE FROM cmdalivrer CMD  WHERE :NEW.numero_commande=CMD.id_cmd;

        tblDates.EXTEND;
        tblDates(tblDates.LAST) := :NEW.date_livraison;
    END IF ;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    IF tblDates.COUNT > 0 THEN
      FOR i IN tblDates.FIRST..tbDates.LAST LOOP
        DELETE FROM Expedition E
          WHERE E.date_livraison = tblDates(i);
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END livraisonfinie_compound;
```

[You can read further on compound triggers here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm#CIHEFGFD).

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you so much . but any other alternative without compound trigger ?

Comment: @H.Hamza - You could have three separate triggers, a package, and a collection instead.  You could probably rename the table, create a view with the name of the table, and create an instead of trigger on the view.